# Creating a single figure from a list of figures in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Supposing I have a list of figures (figList) such as the following (output generated in iPython):

```
In [25]: figList
Out[25]: [<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x63a8d90>,
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x638e3f0>,
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x6669710>,
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x69daeb0>,
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x63a43f0>,
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x6488ad0>,
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x735f6d0>,
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x79f41b0>,
 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7848090>]
```

I want to be able to use figList to generate a figure consisting of a set of subplots each corresponding to one of the elements of figList.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is hard to move axes between figures, which is what you want to do.  It would be better to re-factor the code you used to generate this list to have the functions take axes as an argument and then plot to those axes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if python matplotlib doesn't work, you could write out the images and then use imagemagick to merge the plots and resize it the way you want.